# How can I change the icon of a fogger app

Tags: launcher, icons

I've made several fogger apps (without any code, so basically they're just hyperlinks in the unity launcher). How can I change the icon of these 'apps'? (Do I, for example, need to make a stylesheet?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When creating a fog app, click on the icon left to the name & url field, then select your icon. Or: drag & drop an icon to the new fog app window.
NB: If you want to add an icon to an existing app, first delete the old app and then create a new app with the icon. Replacing a fog app will not lead to an updated icon.

[image: adding an icon to a fog app]

Answer (score 1):

Well you could open the Fogger-App with an editor like Scratch and change the icon. This should look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Music
Comment=Google Music
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Exec=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/fogger/bin/fogger 2c9d692a576395c5d7a2c91b5a101d09
TryExec=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/fogger/bin/fogger
Icon=/usr/share/icons/eNumix-uTouch/apps/48/google-musicmanager.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=fogapp-2c9d692a576395c5d7a2c91b5a101d09
Keywords=fogger;fogapp;
```

You will have to change two app files one for the Launcher and one for fogger.

I use Slingshot on elementary OS Luna and had to changes these app files:

Fogger: 
    /home/USERNAME/.local/share/fogapps/

Slingshot: 
    /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications